# Proof for pythagoras theorem

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $f,g$ orthogonals to each other.

$${\left\| {f + g} \right\|^2} = \left<f,f\right>+\left<g,f\right>+\left<f,g\right>+\left<g,g\right> = {\left\| f \right\|^2} + {\left\| g \right\|^2}$$

Can you please explain the second and third equalities (essentially the whole proof)?

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ orthogonal?

Comment: Oh yes. Let me add this information

Answer (score 2):

The scalar product has is *linear in both arguments* so:

$$||f+g||^2 = \langle f+g , f+g\rangle = \langle f,f+g\rangle+\langle g ,f+g\rangle = \langle f,f\rangle+\langle g ,f\rangle + \langle f,g\rangle+\langle g ,g\rangle = (*)$$

$f$ and $g$ are orthogonal $\iff$ $\langle f,g \rangle = 0$ Because $\langle f,g \rangle = 0 =  \langle g,f \rangle$ we can follow:

$$(*) = \langle f,f\rangle + \langle g ,g\rangle = ||f||^2 + ||g||^2$$

Answer (score 1):

The key is to note that, by definition:
$$
\| x\|^2=
\langle x,x\rangle
$$